# How can I create a new excel file every time a Python script runs?

Tags: python, excel

I have a single source excel file that I clean every month using Python to share only selected data with my team. I would like to create a new excel file every month instead of the same file updated every month.

Ex - I've run the Python script and created a clean file for June. When it runs in July, I would like a new file created instead of June file being updated.

Hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance !

```
import os.path

from datetime import datetime

curr_date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%B')

save_path = 'T:/1. 2021 Timesheets n Bandwidth Tracker/Project Database/RA Copy/'

name_of_file = "PRO Project DB_2021_RA_" + curr_date.upper()

completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".xlsx") 

file1 = open(completeName, "w")
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) indicating the work you have done so far and the problem faced.

Comment: What does your data look like?  How do you read the data from the Excel file?

Answer (score 0):

Could you share the lines of code that saves the file as an .xls or .xlsx file?

Does the code also read in the old excel file?

If you open the Python script and do a Ctrl+F for the file name, that might help.

Easiest solution would be to manually change the file names every month.  Just add:  "Jul21" to the end of the filename in the part of the code that saves it, (next month "Aug21", etc).  And if the old file is loaded into Python, you'll also need to change the file name in there to match.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the code. Basically the code is scheduled to run every month and automatically update the filename with the current month stamp.  Yeah the manually way is probably one way to do it but I was just wondering if there is an automated way to do it .

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably recommend [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) for this, but you'll need a third-party library for that, like [xlsxwriter](https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/) or [openpyxl](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/).

If you don't want to use pandas, below is a simple example for using the library `xlsxwriter`, but it depends on how your data is formatted.  I'm also using `pathlib` since it makes a few things easier.

```py
import xlsxwriter
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime as dt

# Create a folderpath Path object.
output_folder = Path(r"T:/1. 2021 Timesheets n Bandwidth Tracker/Project Database/RA Copy")

# Set your timestamp variables.
today = dt.today()
this_month = today.strftime("%B")   # June
this_year = today.year              # 2021


# Create output path for excel file with month and year added.
full_xl_path = output_folder.joinpath(f"PRO Project DB_{this_year}_RA_{this_month}.xlsx")

# Create workbook and worksheet from given variables.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(full_xl_path)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(name="Sheet1")


# Data sample
columns = ["employee", "date", "hours"]
data = [
    ["john", "2021-06-26", 8],
    ["dan", "2021-06-26", 8],
    ["joanna", "2021-06-27", 8],    
    ]

# For each row
for r in range(0, len(data) + 1):
    # If this is the firs row.
    if r == 0:
        # Write column headers.
        for h in range(len(columns)):
            worksheet.write(r, c, columns[h])    
    else:
        # Reset r to zero for indexing the data set.
        adjusted_r = r - 1
        for c in range(len(data[adjusted_r])):
            worksheet.write(r, c, data[c])
            
# Close workbook once complete.
workbook.close()
```